# vimrc help : trying to map Ctrl-s to :w

Tags: vim

My current .vimrc file is

```
syntax on
colorscheme zellner
set nu
set ruler
set si "Smart indet
map <C-s> :w<cr>
```

I thought the last line would allow me to hit control-s to automatically save while in normal mode?

{
The last line is just the trim downed version of what I really want which is

```
map <C-s> <esc>:w<cr>a
```

}

Am I forgetting something?

I'm using vim 7.3 that came with my mac.

Answer (score 11):

Like mentioned if you want it on both modes you have to just put

```
inoremap <C-s> <esc>:w<cr>a
nnoremap <C-s> :w<cr>a
```

in your .vimrc.

But note that if you are using the terminal vim then you might have a problem
mapping ctrl-s. By default it stops the flow. In that case add the following to your .bashrc (not sure if the same problem in zsh):

```
stty -ixon
```

Comment: I can confirm this is needed for zsh :)

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right, you want

```
:inoremap <C-s> <esc>:w<cr>a
```

Whoops, just read you want it in **normal** mode

```
:nnoremap <C-s> :w<cr>
```

When you're writing commands in vim files (like .vimrc) you don't need the `:`. It is only a method of entering commands on the command line.

Comment: I thought the <esc> automatically, put you in normal, would you still need the imap?  Is that redundant?  Also if Im in the rc file do I need the : at the beginning?  I trying type what you suggested while in the command-line, as well as in the rc file, but it didn't work.Tried you new suggestion as well, no go.

Comment: @DeliciousChris - It is a good practice (some will surely argue) to define this kind of commands separately for different modes. You don't need the --> :    in vimrc, no.

Comment: No, you don't need the imap if you're only interested in doing this from the normal mode.